# can't import uno in python for libreoffice on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, libreoffice

I am on **ubuntu 16.04** with **LO 7.0.1.2** and **python 3.7.6.**
APSO is installed and execution of python scripts in LO works with internal interpreter.

However, in my system  with python 3.7, I get:

> Module not found for line : import uno

libre-office-skript-provider is installed
and I also tried

```
export set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libreoffice/program
```

recommended by
http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html

Does anybody have a hint or trick, how to make it run?

Comment: Did you enter `python3` followed by `import uno` in a terminal? Normally that should work. Since APSO is working, there must be something you are doing wrong. Maybe you could check APSO and see what is different. Also try: http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html

Comment: Many thanks for your respond Jim, i tested in APSO import uno and it works. But in my terminal i checked  gain, latest version as suggested by mrvol (see below) and i still get 'No module named uno'. Probably after spending days on this, i plan to do a testrun of ubuntu 20.01 with a complete new setup. However, this would not be satisfying as 16.04 is fine for me and i'am not sure, if 20.04 would solve my error.

Comment: I haven't tried Anaconda. That may have to do with why it isn't working, and it seems to me that you should have mentioned it in the title or tags of the question. Is APSO using the Anaconda python?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Obviously is aspo using a different console. Here is the output :

Comment: APSO python console [LibreOffice]
3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: How can i bring APSO to use my general pythen on my system with all my installations? Basically this is the goal. To enable Numpy and pandas for subroutines in Libreoffice Base? Or other way around, to bring my general python3 to access Libreoffice?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i bring APSO to use my general pythen on my system with all my installations? Basically this is the goal. To enable Numpy and pandas for subroutines in Libreoffice Base? Or other way around, to bring my general python3 to access Libreoffice?

What generally works for me is a fresh install of Ubuntu with normal python (not Anaconda). Then `python3` followed by `import uno` in a terminal. Sometimes `libreoffice-script-provider-python` is needed, or a similar package for other flavors of Linux.

At that point, it should work to add pandas and numpy using pip. Anaconda can probably be made to work as well, but it may require different steps, and I haven't tried it so I cannot give ideas on what they might be.

Comment: Thanks, yes i think this is the way to go. I just installed 20.04 and working on it. I will post my result. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run?

```
pip install unotools
```

and

```
sudo aptitude install -y libreoffice libreoffice-script-provider-python uno-libs3 python3-uno python3
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, yes i installed everything. In the following i post the anserwers of my console.

Comment: (base) cmoog@E6520:~$ pip install unotoolsRequirement already satisfied: unotools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.3)

Comment: (base) cmoog@E6520:~$ sudo apt install -y libreoffice libreoffice-script-provider-python uno-libs3 python3-uno python3
[sudo] Passwort für cmoog: 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
python3 ist schon die neueste Version (3.5.1-3).
python3-uno ist schon die neueste Version (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10).
uno-libs3 ist schon die neueste Version (5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10).
libreoffice ist schon die neueste Version (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10).

Comment: libreoffice ist schon die neueste Version (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10).
libreoffice-script-provider-python ist schon die neueste Version (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.

Comment: (base) cmoog@E6520:~$ python3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uno'

Comment: Please check for sure that you use the right python env. Cause, you use anaconda, it should be somewhere in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.3)/bla-bla.

Comment: You can also install a new package with `pip`, like `pip install requests` and then in python you can type `import requests`, it should work fine.